jackson Shape.ARRAY /w Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY
is Jackson Object Mapper's ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY feature supposed to work with JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY ??
I have:
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void testCandlesSingleValueWsRes() {
        String singleCandleValue = """
                [158587,[1716181800000,67222,67224,67224,67222,0.0022]]
                """;

        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
                .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        BitfinexOhlcWsResp bitfinexOhlcWsResp = mapper.readValue(singleCandleValue, BitfinexOhlcWsResp.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(bitfinexOhlcWsResp);
    }

with model:
@Data
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class BitfinexOhlcWsResp {
    Integer channelId;

    @JsonFormat(with = {JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY})
    List<BitfinexCandle> candles;
}

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class BitfinexCandle {
    long tstpMs; //Millisecond epoch timestamp
    float open; //First execution during the time frame
    float close; //Last execution during the time frame
    float high; //Highest execution during the time frame
    float low; //Lowest execution during the timeframe
    float volume; //Quantity of symbol traded within the timeframe
}

and I get:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize a POJO (of type `com.broker.connector.bitfinex.entity.BitfinexCandle`) from non-Array representation (token: VALUE_NUMBER_INT): type/property designed to be serialized as JSON Array
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.broker.connector.bitfinex.model.quote.BitfinexOhlcWsResp["candles"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

when I wrap data in another [] it works...
what am I missing?
'jackson-core': v.2.16.1
